# Python equivalent of java junit assertequals

Tags: python

In Java, Junit has some "assert" methods that, when they fail, will tell you something like "Assertion failed. Expected x but saw y".

What's an equivalent library in Python for that, as opposed to "assert x" producing "assertion failed" but not further information?

Comment: You are looking for `unittest`.

Comment: `assert statement, "Error message here"` You can add a custom error message when you use assert statement.

Comment: If you use the `unittest` package, then you can do something like this. `self.assertEqual(True, False, "expected True, but got False")` and that message will be printed when the test fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `assert` keyword you can add customised error messages:

```py
assert your_statement_here, "Custom error message here"
```

Within your custom error message error you can format any variables or data you need to show to debug.

However, if you need something more powerful, as @Asocia said, you will need `unittest`, specifically `assert-methods` is what I think you are looking for, and the official documentation can help with that:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#assert-methods

> - The TestCase class provides several assert methods to check for and
>   report failures.
> - assertEqual(a, b)  checks: a == b
> - assertNotEqual(a, b)  checks: a != b
> - ... and so on